# Create multiple objects from list of strings python

Tags: python-3.x, list, oop

If I were to have a list `aList = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Date']`, and I wanted to make each item in the list an object, for example the equivalent of `Banana = AClass()`. After doing this, I would be able to create and call `self.anything` for each item in the list.

How would I go about doing this?
Here is essentially what I am trying to achieve:

```
import random
class Fruit:
   def __init__(self):
        self.tastiness = random.randint(1,10)

fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Date']
fruits[1] = Fruit()   # Creating a variable from the list
if Banana.tastiness < 5:
    print('Not tasty enough')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: I looked at that, I don't think that helps me

Comment: How not so? It's exactly your question and the answers here are basically duplicates of the answers in that topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your class and list of names, you could use a dict comprehension to create the fruit instances and have reasonable access to them via their names:

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Date']
fruits = {k: Fruit() for k in fruits}

if fruits['Banana'].tastiness < 5:
    print('Not tasty enough')
```

While it is possible to create variables with dynamic names (so that your `Banana.tastiness` would work), I would strongly advice against it.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this is what you want to do:

Using strings as key:

```
dfruits = {}
for f in fruits:
    dfruits[f] = Fruit()
```

Dict comprehension-style

```
dfruits = {i: Fruit() for i in fruits}
```

Using integer keys for the dict:

```
dfruits = {}
for i,f in enumerate(fruits):
    dfruits[i] = Fruit()
```

Or

```
dfruits = {i: Fruit() for i, _ in enumerate(fruits)}
```

Answer (score -1):

You would likely go about doing this by creating a parent class "Fruit" with child classes for "Apple", "Banana" ect

Here is an article that describes the process for doing what you want.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-inheritance-in-python-3

I know you can create an array of objects, where the individual items inherit traits of their individual class, however, I believe these have to initialize your object of type fruit/specific fruit beforehand.

```
x = Apple()
x.taste = "bitter"
list.append(x)
```